# Ajax call always triggers fail handler even though success is returned by the server

Tags: ajax, google-apps-script, error-handling

The following JavaScript always triggers the fail handler even though the return value is success from the server side:

```
$.ajax(payload)
    .done(function(data, statusText, jqxhr) {
            document.getElementById('myModal').innerHTML = "<p>Record Saved ... </p>";
            modal.style.display = "block";
            refresh_html_page(document.getElementById("sheetname").value);
    })
    .fail(function(jqxhr, statusText, errorThrown) {
            document.getElementById('myModal').innerHTML = "<p>Record Not Saved ... </p>";
            modal.style.display = "block";  
            refresh_html_page(document.getElementById("sheetname").value);
    })
    .always(function () {
    // Re-enable the inputs
    $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
    });
```

Returned JSON string:

[{"result":"success","row":11}]

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried logging the error passed to `.fail()`? What do they say? Also: what is the http status code returned by the server?

Comment: Dear Andrew - thank you for your time and query: I modified the fail log as follows: document.getElementById('myModal').innerHTML = "<p>Record Not Saved ... jqxhr = " + jqxhr.responseText + " statusText is: " + statusText + " and errorThrown: "+ errorThrown +"</p>"; and this is what I get: Record Not Saved ... jqxhr = undefined statusText is: error and errorThrown: error; by the way the intended work of record getting saved works and no issues with that it is just that the fail trigger is being called;

Comment: Updated comment: Dear Andrew - thank you for your time and query: I modified the fail log as follows: document.getElementById('myModal').innerHTML = "<p>Record Not Saved ... jqxhr = " + jqxhr.responseText + " HTTP Status code: "+ jqxhr.status + " statusText is: " + statusText + " and errorThrown: "+ errorThrown +"</p>"; and this is what I get: Record Not Saved ... jqxhr = undefined HTTP Status code: 404 statusText is: error and errorThrown: error; by the way the intended work of record getting saved works and no issues with that it is just that the fail trigger is being called;

Comment: Hi @Hussain. If the response is 404 then it is understandable that the fail handler is called. It sounds like the server is returning this status (when it should return an "OK" 2xx status or perhaps a redirect status, 3xx). Is your `payload` using POST or GET and is it a server within your control? Your browser devtools may allow you to see the exact contents of the response including all headers (e.g. using the "Network" Tab in google chrome). Perhaps you could show us some of the contents of `payload`?

Comment: Dear Andrew, Ok to share more details on the work I am doing - I am creating a web page of a form using Google APP Script in a google sheet and then using POST to insert a record in another sheet - that has APP Script to process such requests. The record is getting inserted successfully. The payload is as follows: 


    // Serialize the data in the form
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();

 var payload = {
      url: "https://script.google.com/macros/s/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/exec",
      method: "POST",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: serializedData
 };

Comment: Hi @Hussain I'm not familiar with the API but I think you may have some syntax errors. I'd suggest trying two things to see if they make a difference. 1: try and specify https:// in your url like this `https://script.google.com...`. 2: you have a semicolon that is not necessary at `/exec";,`. Try making this `/exec",`

Comment: Dear Andrew, thank you for your feedback. In fact I had applied both the points before I sent the comment. For some reason when I pasted the code the https was gone and comma became semi coll an; I do not see any issue with the syntax as the record is getting processed at the back end without any error. it is just the return JASON that has issues; will try to post the same action through some other means and see how it works and update the status here. Really appreciate your time and efforts. Thank you very much Andrew and keep it up.

Comment: Dear Andrew - tried looking at the console and I am seeing an error as follows on a success call:"...because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled..." the JSON returned is {result: "success", row: 8} and the return is done as follows from the server:     return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);

Comment: I also tried to use MIME Type as JAVASCRIPT on server side as follows:     return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT); and now I am getting an error as Unexpected token :

Answer (score 0):

Good news. I was able to crack it. The solution was as follows:

1. Set up a call back function in the payload
2. Have a dummy action in the newly created call back function
3. Prefixed the call back function name in the server side while creating the jasonp response

Client side:

```
function handleJSONPResponse(data, status, request) {
   console.log('response', data);
}


// Fire off the request to /form.php
var payload = {
     crossDomain: true,
     url: "https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/exec",
     method: "POST",
     dataType: "jsonp",
     data: serializedData,
     jsonpCallback: 'handleJSONPResponse'
};
```

Server Side (e is the payload sent from client):

```
return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(e.parameters.callback + '(' + JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow})+ ')')
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
```

It was wonderful solving the problem. Thank you very much for your kind inputs and encouragement. Much appreciated.